# Kafka connect update plugin without reload container kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to develop a Kafka connector but for test quickly I would like reload the plugin without reload the container in my docker stack. Is there a way to do it?

Actually I compile the connector and i move the jar file in a folder binded on the container kafka connect. After move the file I reload the container.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to "hot swap" plugins; they are only scanned at startup of the Connect worker process, after the CLASSPATH is also scanned.

You should use unit/integration tests for "quickly testing". If that's not enough, then `connect-standalone` can be used rather than containers